# why is there an error occuring within my functions?

Tags: python, math

For some reason, the outputs to the calculation `multiply = func1_input * 9` gives a repeating number from input e.g. `5555555` if `5` is entered.
Also for the calculation for `sum of digits` the output is what you would expect `multiply` to give.

```py
def function1():
    while True:
        try:
            func1_input = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 9: ")
            val = int(func1_input)
            if 1 <= val <= 9:
                print("You selected: ",func1_input)
                print("\n")
                function2(func1_input)
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid input. Please enter again.")
                function1()
        except ValueError:
            print("number not entered")

def function2(func1_input):

    func2_input = int(input("What is 10-1?: "))
    if func2_input == 9:
        print("Your number is: ",func2_input)
        print("\n")
        multiply = func1_input*9
        print("Your number multiplied by 9 is: ",multiply)
        function3(multiply)
    
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter again.")
        function2(func2_input)

def function3(multiply):
    sum_of_digits = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(multiply))
    print("Adding up the individual digits of your number gives: ",sum_of_digits)
    function4(sum_of_digits)
```

Comment: `func1_input` is a string. Did you mean to pass `val` instead?

Comment: UnholySheep provided the answer, but a different issue is why are you calling function1 in the else clause?  You're in a while loop so unnecessary.  function2 doesn't do this, but it should.  Instead, it recursively calls itself for invalid input, which is frowned upon as a coding practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the line `function2(func1_input)`. It should be `function2(val)`.